# Why are my images not cached although I configured OUTPUTCACHE?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

SO,
I trying to configure caching for my MVC5 application for optimization purposes. Although I put `OutputCache` attribute on a controller action method I can't see my images cached.
Here is the controller action:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, NoStore=true, VaryByParam = "resultid")]
public FileContentResult getPicture(string resultid)
{
   var actionLinks = db.ActionLinks.ToList();
   var actionLinkPic = actionLinks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == resultid);
   if (actionLinks != null)
   {
      return File(actionLinkPic.TPicture, actionLinkPic.TPictureMimeType);
   }
   else
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Here is the network response in firefox:

The network response:

[image]

Comment: Try deleting `NoStore=true`

Comment: That will permanently store those pictures, I don't want that

Answer (score 0):

You have `NoStore=true`

The [NoStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.nostore(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.OutputCacheAttribute.NoStore) property disables caching completely - it is commonly used to disable caching for GET requests (which are cached by default).

Change it to `NoStore=false`

Unfortunately there is very little documentation for OutputCacheAttribute, so to a certain extent you will have to experiment with the options, and see what happens.

Comment: Still it is not cached with `NoStore=false`, what could be the problem?

Comment: And by the way do I need to add configuration for output cache in application web.config?

Comment: Browsers can disable caching, both in code and settings in the developer window. Please could you share the Javascript/HTML which makes the request to getPicture.

Comment: `<img class='activity-picture' src="@Url.Action("getPicture", "ActionLinks", new { resultid = item.Id })" alt="@item.ActionText" />` Here it is.

Comment: Let me add that I don't have any single line of code regarding output caching in my application web config. And also I am testing this application locally